# Define a property in Facelets page

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I know that by using `<f:loadBundle>` I can load whole property file. But is there any tag in Facelets by which I can define a property in Facelets file and can use in Facelets page.

I know this can also be done by controller layer (like `getSomeProperty()`) but I don't want to do this. I am just looking for a tag that do this.

In other words we can do this in XML like this

```
<properties>
  <propertyName>propertyValue</propertyName>
<proprties>
```

So in Facelets how can I do this?

Comment: You was confusingly talking about "XHTML/JSF" all the time, which I fixed to be "Facelets", but now it appears that you actually meant to say "faces-config.xml" (or "web.xml")? What exactly are you now asking? You want to define a constant (which not an i18n property!) in faces-config.xml or web.xml and be able to access it via some EL #{...} in a Facelets page?

Comment: I donot want to define anything in *.xml or *.properties file. All I want to use  a tag (jsf-page) to define a property that use can be used in that jsf page .... Hope you understand now.

Comment: Why did you edit "Facelets" to "XML" then? This got me confused and now it appears that it's actually yourself who's confused. In any case, you'd do yourself and us a big favour if you elaborate the functional requirement in detail, for which you possibly incorrectly thought that this all would be the right solution. I.e. what problem exactly are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define a vanilla page-scoped variable using either JSTL. Using JSTL's [`<c:set/>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/c/set.html):

```
<c:set var="propertyName" value="propertyValue"/>
```

You could then use `#{propertyName}` anywhere within your page.