# JSF input processing order

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to specify the order in which the inputs should be set after a submit?

Here is my case:

```
<h:inputText id="fieldA" value=#{myBean.myObject.fieldA}" />
<h:inputText id="fieldB" value=#{myBean.myObject.fieldB}" />
<p:autoComplete id="myObject" value=#{myBean.myObject" converter="myObjectConverter" />
<h:inputText id="fieldC" value=#{myBean.myObject.fieldD}" />
<h:inputText id="fieldD" value=#{myBean.myObject.fieldC}" />
```

The issue I am encountering is that, as the inputs are processed in the ordered they are declared, fieldA and fieldB are set in the initial instance of myObject, then myObject is set (with a new instance thus filedA and fieldB values are lost), and finally fieldC and fieldD are set with no problem.

If I could manage to start by setting myObject first, that would solve my problem.

I will temporarily set the fields and myObject into two different attributes of my bean, and populate myObject after clicking a save button. But it looks more like a hack than a real solution.

Needless to say that declaring the autocomplete before the inputtexts is not an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a case like that, I would usually define `fieldA` and `fieldB` (and even `fieldC` and `fieldD` as properties of myBean, and apply the values to `myObject` when accessing the object from the controller.

Comment: I updated my previous (wortless) answer, please see it :)

Answer (score 0):

In shortcut:
You can use `<p:inputText>` tag from primefaces. Then, you can disable all inputs. Add ajax to your autoComplete, and update other inputs after processing autoComplete. Inputs `disable` attribute can be set to depend on whether the autoComplete is not null. This way you will make the user to enter the autoComplet first.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>you can try to set `immediate="true"` to `p:autocomplete`, so that it will be processed in the `APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES` phase, before all other components.</strike>

The simple solution is to update `h:inputText`s when `p:autocomplete` item is selected to reflect its values:

```
<p:autoComplete id="myObject" value="#{myBean.myObject}" ...>
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@this" update="fieldA fieldB fieldC fieldD" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

but this reverts user inputs on `h:inputText`s. And since you can't move `p:autocomplete` on top, probably this is not acceptable too.

In case you can't/don't want to use ajax, you can force an early model update:

```
<p:autoComplete id="myObject" value="#{myBean.myObject}" immediate="true" 
    valueChangeListener="#{component.updateModel(facesContext)}" ... />
```

but, in my opinion, this is not very user friendly...

P.S. this time it's tested :)

Comment: Hi Michele, the p:autocomplete is not always selectable: I can't force selection since I have to create a new Entity if none is selected from the existing ones: if no suggestion is selected from the autocomplete, the input value is returned as is to the converter who creates a new instance to be persisted. Also even when an autocomplete suggestion is selected and the corresponding inputs updated, we have to be able to update one of its fields (fieldA-D) through these same inputs.

Comment: Can you post the converter code and full autocomplete tag?

Answer (score 0):

There's no pretty way to get around this; your situation is already less than ideal and is hacky (re: not being able to simply reorder the fields). One workaround is for you to set `fieldA` and `fieldB` as attributes of `myObject`. In the converter, you could then pull the values off the components. Observe

1. Set attributes thus

   ```
   <h:inputText id="fieldA" binding=#{fieldA}" />
   <h:inputText id="fieldB" binding=#{fieldB}" />
   <p:autoComplete id="myObject" value=#{myBean.myObject" converter="myObjectConverter">
       <f:attribute name="fieldA" value="#{fieldA}"/>
       <f:attribute name="fieldB" value="#{fieldB}"/>
   </p:autoComplete>
   ```

   The `binding` attribute effectively [turns those components into page-scoped variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981258/define-a-property-in-facelets-page/27992567#27992567), allowing you to then pass them as attributes on your `p:autocomplete`
2. Get the values of those variables in your converter

   ```
   //Retrieve the fields and cast to UIInput, necessary
   //to retrieve the submitted values
   UIInput fieldA = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("fieldA");
   UIInput fieldB = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("fieldB");

   //Retrieve the submitted values and do whatever you need to do
   String valueA = fieldA.getSubmittedValue().toString();
   String valueB = fieldB.getSubmittedValue().toString();
   ```

More importantly, *why can't you just reorder the fields/logical flow of your form*? You can avoid all this nasty business if you did